# Scale invariant goodness of fit for one model's fit across multiple datasets

Tags: modeling, goodness-of-fit

Suppose I have one model, and (in my case) tens of thousands of datasets. I'm interested in scoring how well this one model fits across all datasets, and the comparison is more to identify a subset of datasets where this model seems to hold.

Normally when we consider goodness of fit, we're comparing multiple models' fit to a one set of observations. Here, RMS, Akaike, BIC etc all apply. However in this circumstance all of these measures tend to correlate with the range of data. Each dataset can have y-values that range from values of 1-100, to 1-100000, and are negative exponential (or multiple negative exponential) in shape; these classic goodness of fit values tend to be proportional the highest value in the dataset, even if the residuals look random and the visual appearance of the fit is excellent.

Mean relative error has been the closest, but still seems to penalize higher-ranged datasets more so than poor fit. **Is there an error that is scale invariant**? Or scales to the max, or range of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Normalized root-mean-square-deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation#Normalization), using the range in the denominator worked extremely well for my dataset. Also tried MAE (see same link), did not work as well.